# Ajax http 500 error

Tags: php, ajax

New to StackExchange, although I have read a lot on here. My problem: an Ajax error.

```
HTTP Result Code: 500
Path /system/ajax
no status text or response text.
```

This just started on a website that was working fine. I have tried increasing PHP's memory, but that isn't working either. The error report says this:

> "Notice: Undefined property: stdClass::$data in uc_ups_quote()"
> (line 726 of /my/path)

And:

> "Exception: String could not be parsed as XML in SimpleXMLElement->__construct()"
> (line 726 of same/path)

Line 726 of that file is: `$response = new SimpleXMLElement($resp->data);`

Any help is appreciated. I couldn't find the answer anywhere else.

Comment: how much code do you need for context?

Comment: Well, it looks like some various things are all either not defined, or defined incorrectly, so the problem could be miles ahead of the fatal error. You should just back trace and start with the Notice first.

Comment: ok, I'm really green so bear with me. The line 726 is the error and the undefined property and the exception are not on that line.

Comment: @Burlyn84 What is the URL of the script you are calling?

Comment: https://www.excellpropetfoods.com/misc/jquery.js?v=1.4.4 not sure if that is what you need or not. As I said I'm green on this whole thing. I work for a company whose modus operandi is learn by doing

Comment: To translate what PHP is saying: `$resp` is an object but it does not contain a property called `data`. This is not necessarily a problem, so it's only a notice. But, since `$resp->data` doesn't exist, you're doing `new SimpleXMLElement(*nothing*)` and that's not valid. That's why that is an exception and you're getting a 500 error. You need to investigate why `$resp` does not contain a `data` property.